# Помогите пожалуйста с блоком?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg

Каким образом можно разместить в одном блоке из картинки кнопку поиска, как на картинке!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не сильно понял вопрос, но если я понял правильно, то можно задать картинку через background и в этом же блоке позиционировать кнопку

Comment: разметка нужна,вариантов стилизовать на одном уровне много

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из возможных вариантов

```css
.block {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.block__left {
  margin-right: 80px;
}
.block__right {
  display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.block__field {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__left">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/700x100">
  </div>
  <div class="block__right">
    <input type="text" class="block__field">
    <input type="submit" value="BTN">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо помог оч   !